# Collecting records from different sites in a single MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert into a single MySQL DB (main domain) records coming from different sites.
Each domain has its own PHP file which assembles the record and should run an INSERT query accessing, with credentials, the main DB.
The relevant starting code of PHPs is:

```
$host     = 'localhost';
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';
$db_name  = 'main_db';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$db_name);
```

I'm confused by the 'localhost' definition; actually it should point to a remote host (with which syntax?), or not?

Possibly the question is silly, but before tampering with files and DBs I would appreciate any indication, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$host     = 'localhost'; // for local machine
```

For remote host use hostname or ip address

```
$host     = 'myhost.mydomain.org'; // using hostname 

$host     = '12.123.123.12' ; // like this using IP
```

Most important things are as follows (on your remote machine) :

- **firewall** of the server must be set-up to enable incomming connections on port ( default 3306 or any other )
- **Permission** - you must have a user in MySQL who is allowed to connect from % ( host / IP ), which will be something like below for all databases

  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO USER-NAME@IP IDENTIFIED BY "PASSWORD";`
- **`bind-address`** in my.cnf, Most default installs of MySQL only listen to the local machine (`bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP`)

Then restart your mysql server

There is nice [blog](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) may help you to understand clearly.

Comment: Akshay: I left a comment but it is not shown: Retry.

Comment: Akshay: I left a comment but it is not shown: Retry. Your suggestions were useful because I had something to communicate to my ISP. The attempts using the host port failed. The ISP finally found a solution, actually working, but with several doubts on my side. I had to assign to '$host' an IP address I got from the ISP. This IP is the ISP internal network where my two domains are configured. I think this is a 'short way' solution, not particularly elegant. What if they change this IP? I submitted your blog's url, but I'm not sure they have considered it.

Comment: if your system can resolve hostname corresponding to internal ips given by isp, there will be no issue, in /etc/hosts file you can set ip of your 2 machines, and in script use hostname, and those 2 machines should be able to communicate your main server, meaning firewall should not block.